# Unable to use Environment.GetResourceString static method

Tags: c#, compact-framework, environment

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = Environment.GetResourceString("test"); //compile-time error
        }
    }
}
```

The error is: 'System.Environment' does not contain a definition for 'GetResourceString'.

**EDIT**: OP has stated that he's using the Compact Framework, v3.5.

I dont get the picture, what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Environment.GetResourceString` appears to be present, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getresourcestring%28VS.80%29.aspx), only in version 2.0 of the Compact Framework.  If the article is to be believed, it's never existed in the standard framework.

What are you trying to do?  If it's localization you're after, you may want `ResourceManager.GetString`.

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager myManager = new 
   System.Resources.ResourceManager("ResourceNamespace.myResources", 
   myAssembly);

// Retrieves String and Image resources.
string myString = myManager.GetString("StringResource");
```

Comment: So is it Compact Framework only? (I'm targeting .NET 3.5) Yes it would be for localization. How come some class in the BCL are using this method (according to Reflector)?

Comment: Are you trying to use this method after observing that some of the BCL internals use it?  I wouldn't recommend that.  My guess is, the method is marked `internal`, and possibly is marked with `InternalsVisibleTo`, to allow use from within the BCL, but not outside it.

Comment: The ResourceManager is supported in the CF, and its use would be the correct approach.

Answer (score 8):

Environment.GetResourceString is not public

```
internal static string GetResourceString(string key);
```

See Michael Petrottas answer for how to access resources or have a look at the samples here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access `Environment.GetResourceString`, but if you need access to mscorlib's internal error message, define your own implementation of that.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;

static class EnvironmentEx
{
    // Mscorlib's resources.
    private static ResourceSet resources = null;

    // Gets mscorlib's internal error message.
    public static string GetResourceString(string name)
    {
        if (resources == null)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(object));
            var assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name;
            var manager = new ResourceManager(assemblyName, assembly);
            resources = manager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        }
        return resources.GetString(name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name)));
    }

    // Gets parametrized mscorlib's internal error message.
    public static string GetResourceString(string name, params object[] args)
    {
        return string.Format(GetResourceString(name), args);
    }
    
    static void Main()
    {
        string message = GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Bounds_Lower_Upper", -1, 1);
        // message = "Argument must be between -1 and 1".
    }
}
```

P. S. [Here](https://github.com/ng256/Tools/blob/main/MscorlibMessage.md) a list of all messages with their ID.