# Environment.GetResourceString

Tags: c#

I  had to reverse engineering other vendor code .Since i have to hack his code.I jumped few problem but still can understand c# code(** I'm a php oop developer full time).The only last part  was Enviroment.GetResourceString was not found.Some said  it was in .net framework 2.0.I have install .net framework 2.0 sdk and also compact edition.But still visual web developer cannot find the function.Any idea to change Enviroment.GetResouceString to other function ?
Operating System : Windows 2008 r2 Web Edition 64 bit

throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxValue", string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_MustBePositive"), new object[] { "maxValue" }));

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question:
[Unable to use Environment.GetResourceString static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794084/unable-to-use-environment-getresourcestring-static-method)

Answer (score 1):

It existed in the 2.0 **Compact** Framework but never (as a public method) anywhere else.

See this answer: [Unable to use Environment.GetResourceString static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794084/unable-to-use-environment-getresourcestring-static-method)

Comment: Both push the same website but still not the answer
  System.Resources.ResourceManager only have CreateFileResourceManager,Equals,HeaderVersionNumber,MagicNumber and ReferenceEquals

Comment: The referenced answer (top anwer) answers your question.

Comment: i have repair the bug.I used some software to reverse it.As my found out the random class used the Enviroment.GetResourceString is internal .Net framework classes.So no need me ,to write the same class Random.Quite odd since why internal classes can talk private method while outside classes cannot talk.